# Unable to find an error

Tags: reactjs, unexpected-token

i know it's a minor and maybe a fool question but i'm stuck for about an hour at an error which i cant see. This is my code:

```
const ModalRoot = ({ modalType, modalProps, locale }) => {
  if (!modalType) {
    return <span />;
  }

  return (
    <IntlProvider
      locale={locale}
      key={locale}
      messages={messagesFor(locale)}
    >
      <div className="backdrop">
        {renderAppropriateModal(modalType, modalProps)}
      </div>
    </IntlProvider>
  );
};
```

The console shows an error in the if saying unexpected token. Why is this happening??

Comment: What is the *exact* error. Is it, for example, "unexpected token <"?

Comment: It is saying Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: are you using something like babel?

Answer (score 0):

This can be your error...

check this samples.

**Wrong place to declare.**

```
import React from 'react';

class YOURCLASS extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

   }

   //do not place this ModalRoot here
   const ModalRoot = ({ modalType, modalProps, locale }) => {
      //contents
   }

   render(){
     return(
        <div>{yourContent}</div>
     );
   }
}
```

**Right place to declare**

```
import React from 'react';

//Place it here outside the class YOURCLASS
const ModalRoot = ({ modalType, modalProps, locale }) => {
      //contents
}

class YOURCLASS extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

   }



   render(){
     return(
        <div>{yourContent}</div>
     );
   }
}
```

if you still intends to do it inside class... better use function instead...

```
import React from 'react';

class YOURCLASS extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

   }

   //function type ModalRoot
   ModalRoot(modalType, modalProps, locale){
      //contents
      return <IntlProvider />;
   }

   render(){
     const {modalType, modalProps, locale} = this.props;
     let yourContent = this.ModalRoot(modalType, modalProps, locale);
     return(
        <div>{yourContent}</div>
     );
   }
}
```

hope it helps...